# How do I make the radius of a circle alternate between a bigger and smaller radius in processing in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I think this could be achieved by setting a **minimum** and **maximum** radius of the circle. But I am new to processing and don't know how to go about doing it correctly. I mean to give it a **pulse effect**.

Comment: Have you done any research yet? The first result for ["pulsing circle p5.js"](https://editor.p5js.org/dansakamoto/sketches/H1ICcXXtm) seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  fill(0);
}

int x = 60;
boolean go_Up = true;

void draw() {
  background(255);
  translate(width/2, height/2);

  if (x <= 40)
    go_Up = true;
  else if (x >= 80)
    go_Up = false;

  if (go_Up)
    x++;
  else
    x--;

  circle(0, 0, x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the program running but only the pulsing effect doesn't work. So we will just take a look at the code:

```
var radius;

radius = random(minimumRadius, maximumRadius)

ellipse(x,y, radius*2, radius*2); //if it gets too big then don't multiply by 2
```

It will go inside the `draw()` function.
You can use Perlin noise if you want to make it more smoother, kinda natural you know. But that depends on what we are trying to achieve.